# Topological Sort Space Complexity

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity, topological-sort

Here is the topological sort algorithm, I checked everywhere and I always found the space complexity as O(V) which is the size of the stack, but what I don't understand is: Why nobody considers this is a recursive solution. So, recursion also adds to space complexity and I think it is actually O(V+E).

```
void topologicalVisit(GraphNode node, Stack<GraphNode> stack) {
  ArrayList<GraphNode> neighbors = getNeighbors(node);
  for (GraphNode neighbor : neighbors) {
    if (!neighbor.isVisited) {
      topologicalVisit(neighbor, stack);
    }
  }
  node.isVisited = true;
  stack.push(node);
}

void topologicalSort() {
  Stack<GraphNode> stack = new Stack<>();
  for (GraphNode node : nodeList) {
    if (!node.isVisited) {
      topologicalVisit(node, stack);
    }
  }

  while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print(stack.pop().name + " ");
  }
}
```

(I am sorry, I am just new with algorithm and ds)

Answer (score 1):

You may be right that this particular implementation uses O(+) space in the worst case. It depends on how `getNeighbors` is implemented. If that method creates a new `ArrayList` and returns it, then this will consume O() memory in the worst case.

But that would be particular to that implementation. If `getNeighbors` would return the internal `neighbors` arraylist itself, then no auxiliary memory is allocated other than the local variable `neighbors` (This may be bad practice as such a getter still allows the caller to mutate that list in the graph's data structure). Or, the graph's API could have given an iterator over the neighbors. Either way the call stack would only have needed O() space. With an iterator it would be something like:

```java
void topologicalVisit(GraphNode node, Stack<GraphNode> stack) {
  ListIterator<GraphNode> neighborIterator = getNeighborIterator(node);
  while(neighborIterator.hasNext()) {
    GraphNode neighbor = neighborIterator.next();
    if (!neighbor.isVisited) {
      topologicalVisit(neighbor, stack);
    }
  }
  node.isVisited = true;
  stack.push(node);
}
```

Some notes though:

- The *depth* of the recursion is limited by the number of nodes, not by the number of edges. As the graph is assumed to be a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (a precondition for topological sort), a node is not visited more than once in a single recursion path; there is no path into recursion that is longer than the number of nodes (minus one).
- If it is *not* guaranteed that the graph is a DAG, then this code could get into an infinite recursion, as it could run over a cycle. To protect your code against a graph that has cycles, you should add a separate state for when a node is being expanded (i.e. it is on the recursion path), so that you would detect a cycle and could raise an exception. See [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Depth-first_search) depth-first algorithm where they use a *temporary mark* for this purpose.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what would change it in terms of space. I feel like they are the same thing

Comment: An iterator only allocates the iterator object itself (O(1)) and **one** item reference. An ArrayList will allocate as many entries as there are neighbors. See the difference?

Comment: I am assuming here that `getNeighbors` returns a new array. If however, that method returns an existing array reference, then it doesn't represent extra memory, and we have O(). I have updated my question to clarify this point.